# Can we print mailing lables from CiviCRM?

Tags: mailing

I cannot find a function that allows us to print mailing labels.  Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

1. Search for the contacts you want to print the labels for
2. Select the contacts
3. Go to Actions / Mailing labels - print (see attachment)

[image: CiviCRM - Mailing labels print]

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in the this online book.  [Civicrm Books](http://book.civicrm.org/user/common-workflows/postal-mail-communications/)

Basically if you query of the contacts and select the ones you want, the action pulldown menu has a print mailing labels.